# Editing AD accounts with PHP/ASP.net AND having seamless auth

Tags: php, iis, authentication, active-directory

I am somewhat familiar with how to set up seamless authentication in PHP/ASP.net applications with IIS in a corporate network, but I have a question that so far I have struggled to find an answer to.

With anonymous auth disabled, and windows auth enabled, i.e. seamless authentication is set up, will a PHP/ASP.net script with functionality for adding/modifying users in Active Directory (into the same "container") simply just work for someone with the correct admin privileges, i.e. in php use of just `ldap_bind($conn);`, or must I force the user to supply login credentials to use in the `ldap_bind()` function?

Please understand that I have limited knowledge and understanding of AD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, an LDAP request is transmitted on a connection where that connection has a particularly *authorization state* and the LDAP client examines the response from the server for indications of success or failure. The authorization state of the connection is changed by a successful `bind` request.

Successful requests are therefore dependent on the authorization state of the connection. Properly secured LDAP servers should require applications to `bind` (to change the authorization state of the connection) in order for certain requests (such as `add` and `modify`, `search and`compare`) to be successful.

Comment: Sure, with PHP/ASP.net running as some sort of module of IIS, and with "seamless Windows authentication" setup, would bind commands made in the PHP/ASP.net application be passed up to IIS to pass on to the LDAP server, in which case if a simple bind command was issued with no credentials, would IIS not automatically negotiate a properly authorized connection instead of leaving it as anonymous?

In other words, is it or is it not possible with seamless authentication, to have a web page that allows editing of Active Directory user records, without the user having to supply a password into it?

Comment: The answer depends on the configuration of the server. Generally speaking, servers should be configured to reject unauthenticated requests, and to reject bind requests with no password, but that level of security is not always implemented. Consult your directory services administrators.

Comment: I was assuming a properly secured service, so I take it that's a no. Sorry for the late response, thanks for answering.